# Wiremock returning wrong content-type for Spring Cloud Contract stub runner

Tags: spring, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying out Spring-Cloud-Contract for the first time. I'm trying to have my client auto-discover the contract stubs, but even though my contract specifies a content-type of 'application/json' on the response, what I get from WireMock has a content-type of 'application/octet'. What am I doing wrong?

I have a simple method in my service which returns a model like this from a `/status` endpoint:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "status": string
}
```

My contract looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    request {
        method('GET')
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
        url("/status")
    }

    response {
        status OK()
        body(
                name: "Demo",
                status: "RUNNING"
        )
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```

In my client, I have a class which uses a Spring `RestTemplate` to query this endpoint:

```
@Component
public class StatusClient {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public StatusClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.restTemplate
                .exchange("http://localhost:8080/status", HttpMethod.GET, null, Status.class)
                .getBody();
    }
}

@Data
class Status implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String status;
}
```

My unit test uses `@AutoConfigureStubRunner` to pull the latest version of the contract from the local repository and assert against the response from the contract (eg name = Demo, status = RUNNING).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.example:contract-demo:+:8080"}, stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
public class StatusClientTests {

    @Autowired
    private StatusClient client;

    @Test
    public void testThatStatusReturnsSuccessfully() {
        Status result = this.client.getStatus();
        assertEquals("Demo", result.getName());
        assertEquals("RUNNING", result.getStatus());
    }
}
```

When I run the test, WireMock reports the contract it received as expected:

> ```
> 2018-05-31 11:36:49.919  INFO 14212 --- [tp1255723887-26] WireMock                                 : Request received:
> 127.0.0.1 - GET /status
>
> User-Agent: [Java/1.8.0_161]
> Connection: [keep-alive]
> Host: [localhost:8080]
> Accept: [application/json, application/*+json]
>
>
>
> Matched response definition:
> {
>   "status" : 200,
>   "body" : "{\"name\":\"Demo\",\"status\":\"RUNNING\"}",
>   "headers" : {
>     "contentType" : "application/json"
>   },
>   "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]
> }
>
> Response:
> HTTP/1.1 200
> contentType: [application/json]
> ```

But when the RestTemplate tries to deserialize it, it throws an exception because the response content type is actually "application/octet" once it hits the methods to extract the data:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.example.contractclientdemo.Status] and content type [application/octet-stream]

    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
    at com.example.contractclientdemo.StatusClient.getStatus(StatusClient.java:18)
```

I'm using Finchley.RC2 for the Spring cloud version, and `spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner` is my only test dependency other than `spring-boot-starter-test`.

I know WireMock is returning the wrong content type because I debugged deep into the HttpMessageConverterExtractor class in Spring and that's what the `getContentType` method returned when queried.

Why is WireMock returning the wrong content type, though it reports the correct one in the log? And how can I get it to properly return an `application/json` so I can deserialize my simple message?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I have exactly the same one and it's 03.2019...

Comment: I got it working by explicitly setting the content-type in the request headers when I made the RestTemplate call. I think that the fact that my contract specified application/json as the content type on the request header definition made this necessary. Not sure why it would turn around and actually return the response as application/octet, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem than you. I solved it by adding

```
headers {
  header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
}
```

to the response.
You seem to have in your response, although written in another way, but that did solve the problem in my case. So this have something to do with it.

Before making the change, curl showed no Content-Type response header :

> curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:6565/products/ABC
>   * Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6565 (#0)
>   GET /products/ABC HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:6565
>   User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
>   Accept:application/json
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
>
> Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

```
{  
  "price": {  
    "currencyCode": "EUR",  
    "value": "100.50"  
  },  
  "name": "Fake product"  
}
```

After doing the change, curl returned this and the RestTemplate managed to deserialize it.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)

Here's my working contract :

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract
Contract.make {
    description "should return product information"
    request{
        method GET()
        url("/products/ABC")
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
        body([
          name: 'Fake product',
          price:[
              currencyCode: 'EUR',
              value: 100.50
          ]
        ])
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you should file it as an issue in WireMock. Also you're not setting the application / json content type header in the request explicit. Maybe that's a problem? Also shouldn't it be content-type as the header name in the response stub?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add content type as xml to the mocked response body

```
        stubFor(post(urlMatching("/xyz"))
            .willReturn(ok("""
                            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                            <response>
                              <number>784658522</number>
                            </response>
                    """).withHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.XML.toString())));
```